# Solr - highlight query phrase

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solandra

Is it possible to highlight whole query terms? f.e. when I ask for **"United States"** I want to get:

```
<em>United States</em>
```

and not:

```
<em>United</em> <em>States</em>
```

I've searched the whole Internet for an answer, used all combinations of **hl.mergeContiguous**, **hl.usePhrasesHighlighter** and **hl.highlightMultiTerm** parameters and still cannot make it work.

my query is:

```
http://localhost:8983/solandra/idxPosts.proj350_139/select?q=post_text:"Janusz Palikot"&hl=true&hl.fl=post_text&hl.mergeContiguous=true&hl.usePhrasesHighlighter=true&hl.highlightMultiTerm=true
```

the answer is:

```
...
<arr name="post_text"><str>Tag: <em>janusz</em> <em>palikot</em> - Sowiniec: "Sowiniec"</str></arr>
...
```

my "post_text" field is:

```
<field name="post_text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" required="true" />
```

my "text" type is:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_pl.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_pl.txt" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I also tried to use **FastVectorHighlighter** with **hl.useFastVectorHighlighter=true** but encountered an error:

```
Problem accessing /solandra/idxPosts.proj350_139/select. Reason:

    -6

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -6
    at lucandra.TermFreqVector.getOffsets(TermFreqVector.java:224)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.vectorhighlight.FieldTermStack.<init>(FieldTermStack.java:100)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.vectorhighlight.FastVectorHighlighter.getFieldFragList(FastVectorHighlighter.java:175)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.vectorhighlight.FastVectorHighlighter.getBestFragments(FastVectorHighlighter.java:166)
    at org.apache.solr.highlight.DefaultSolrHighlighter.doHighlightingByFastVectorHighlighter(DefaultSolrHighlighter.java:509)
    at org.apache.solr.highlight.DefaultSolrHighlighter.doHighlighting(DefaultSolrHighlighter.java:376)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent.process(HighlightComponent.java:116)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:194)
    ...
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: did you ever find a way to mark the whole phrase (and only that) in the Solr results? ... I know this is years later, but I still cannot find a working answer

Answer (score 7):

For the phrase highlight, there is a [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-575) stilling waiting to get through to the Solr code.

Answer (score -1):

Chech the [solr doc](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters) for this, there is parameter hl, set this true.